# Create SQL query with dynamic WHERE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgresql as my database, in case that's helpful, although I'd like to find a pure SQL approach instead of a Postgresql specific implementation.

I have a large set of test data obtained from manufacturing a piece of electronics and I'd like to take that set of data and extract from it which units met certain criteria during test, ideally using a separate table that contains the test criteria from each step of manufacturing.

As a simple example, let's say I check the temperature readback from the unit in two different steps of the test.  In step 1, the temperature should be in the range of 20C-30C while step 2 should be in the range of 50C-60C.

Let's assume the following table structure with a set of example data (table name 'test_data'):

```
temperature   step   serial_number
    25          1        1
    55          2        1
    19          1        2
    20          2        2
```

and let's assume the following table that contains the above mentioned pass criteria (table name 'criteria'):

```
temperature_upper   temperature_lower   step
        20                 30              1
        50                 60              2
```

At the moment, using a static approach, I can just use the following query:

```
    SELECT * FROM test_data  WHERE       
  ( test_data.step = 1 AND test_data.temperature > 20 AND test_data.temperature < 30 ) OR   
  ( test_data.step = 2 AND test_data.temperature > 50 AND test_data.temperature < 60 );
```

which would effectively yield the following table:

```
temperature   step   serial_number
    25          1        1
    55          2        1
```

I'd like to make my select query more dynamic and instead of begin statically defined, make it construct itself off of a list of results from the test_criteria table.  The hope is to grow this into a complex query where temperature, voltage and current might be checked in step 1 but only current in step 2, for example.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: You'd use a join between the tables, `ON (test_data.step = criteria.step) AND (test_data.temperature BETWEEN criteria.temperature_lower AND criteria.temperature_upper)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve using a join between the tables

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test_data  t
INNER JOIN criteria c ON t.step =  c.step 
  AND t.temperature > c.temperature_upper 
      AND t.temperature < c.temperature_lower
```

OR if you want >=  and <=

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test_data  t
INNER JOIN criteria c ON t.step =  c.step 
  AND t.temperature netween c.temperature_upper AND  c.temperature_lower
```