# Dynamically formed SQL query based on table data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgresql as my database, in case that's helpful, although I'd like to find a pure SQL approach instead of a Postgresql specific implementation.

I have a large set of test data obtained from manufacturing a piece of electronics and I'd like to take that set of data and extract from it which units met certain criteria during test, ideally using a separate table that contains the test criteria from each step of manufacturing.

As a simple example, let's say I check the temperature and voltage readback from the unit in two different steps of the test and check it against thresholds.

Let's assume the following table structure with a set of example data (table name 'test_data'):

```
temperature  voltage  step   serial_number
    25          10      1        1
    55          15      2        1
    19          17      1        2
    20          20      2        2
```

and let's assume the following table that contains the criteria for a passing unit (table name 'criteria'):

```
column_name     lower   upper   step
temperature      20      30      1
temperature      50      60      2
   voltage       9       11      1
   voltage       14      16      2
```

A static query that does not read from the criteria table would be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM test_data  WHERE       
  ( test_data.step = 1 AND test_data.temperature > 20 AND test_data.temperature < 30 AND test_data.voltage > 9 AND test_data.voltage < 11) OR   
  ( test_data.step = 2 AND test_data.temperature > 50 AND test_data.temperature < 60 AND test_data.voltage > 14 AND test_data.voltage < 16 );
```

My goal is to not have a static query, but instead have the query itself be built upon a dynamic set of data in the criteria table, that can contain any number of rows containing criteria.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: . . If this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57938136/create-sql-query-with-dynamic-where-statement/57944672#57944672, please explain why.

Comment: The example query that I posted in this post does not read at all from the criteria table... my question is how can I use SQL to formulate a query based on the contents of the criteria table.  My goal is to use this dyanmic query as a view that can be used to create test reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate strings twice to generate `WHERE` condition text.

```
select STRING_AGG(stepexpr, ' or ')
from (
   select '(step = ' || step || ' and ' || STRING_AGG(column_name || ' > ' || lower || ' and ' || column_name || ' < ' || upper, ' and ') || ')' stepexpr
   from criteria
   group by step
) t;
```

Result

```
(step = 2 and temperature > 50 and temperature < 60 and voltage > 14 and voltage < 16) or (step = 1 and temperature > 20 and temperature < 30 and voltage > 9 and voltage < 11)
```

Comment: Thanks Serg!  This does the trick... now I need to figure out how to take the result of this and insert it into a WHERE clause... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    serial_number,
    temperature,
    voltage
FROM (   
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE 
            WHEN column_name = ‘temperature’ AND A.temperature >= B.lower AND A.temperature <= B.upper THEN ‘passed_temp_criteria’ 
        ELSE ‘failed’
        END AS temp_check,
        CASE
            WHEN column_name = ‘voltage’ AND A.voltage >= B.lower AND A.voltage <= B.upper THEN ‘passed_volt_criteria’ 
            ELSE ‘failed’ 
        END AS volt_check 
    FROM test_data A
    JOIN criteria B
    ON A.step = B.step
) C 
WHERE temp_check != ‘failed’ AND volt_check != ‘failed’
```